# Authorization Code with PKCE flow - http redirections

Tags: authentication, https, single-page-application, okta, pkce

I have an OKTA client configured for Web Flow Login (Single Page App, Authorization Code Flow with PKCE). My URIs for redirection uses http, not https. Now before redirection to OKTA for authentication, I see an error in a browser:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AuthSdkError: PKCE requires a modern browser with encryption support running in a secure context.
The current page is not being served with HTTPS protocol. PKCE requires secure HTTPS protocol.
AuthSdkError: PKCE requires a modern browser with encryption support running in a secure context.
The current page is not being served with HTTPS protocol. PKCE requires secure HTTPS protocol.
```

which clearly suggests using https instead of http.
Is it the only solution? Or maybe there is a workaround for that? It regards development environment of my app, so it doesn't need to be super secured. (edited)

Comment: You can run it on your localhost with `http`, it will work, as a development, temporary solution

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev that is right, I have no problem with this authentication flow locally. The point is I need to deploy app on DEV environment. Also I'm wondering where I should use https: only on load balancer part, or also behind load balancer where concrete app is running.

Comment: For the library it'll be sufficient to know that you are hosted on https. From the security standpoint you need to follow your rules. Some companies do SSL termination on LB and then it can go http

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a setting in the SDK that will allow you to use PKCE without HTTPS? The PKCE specification does not require HTTPS to be used when sending challenges and codes. In fact, PKCE was introduced because in a mobile environment OAuth requests and responses were partly not secured by TLS — TLS is terminated in the browser, and the response that goes from the browser to the app is unprotected.

If you're not able to change it in the SDK, you can create self-signed certificates with the `openssl` tool, and set up your app to use HTTPS even on localhost (you will get warnings from the browser about the certificate, but at least it will be running HTTPS).